# Editing specific line of text file in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to change the specific line of the text file in asp.net.
Can I change/Replace the text in a particular line only??
I have used the replace function in text file but it is replacing text in entire file.
I want to replace only one line specified by me.

Waiting for the reply..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Need more information about what you have tried, what is the programmatic rule for determining which line to change. Also, StackOverflow is about helping you solve your problems, not writing code for you; although some people will if you show that you have tried to solve the problem first.

Comment: Yes you can read from the file line by line using a StreamReader.ReadLine(), and then search that line for whatever text you need to replace.

Answer (score 6):

File systems don't generally allow you to edit within a file *other* than directly overwriting byte-by-byte. *If* your text file uses the same number of bytes for every line, then you can very efficiently replace a line of text - but that's a relatively rare case these days.

It's more likely that you'll need to take one of these options:

- Load the whole file into memory using `File.ReadAllLines`, change the relevant line, and then write it out again using `File.WriteAllLines`. This is inefficient in terms of memory, but really simple to code. If your file is small, it's a good option.
- Open the input file and a new output file. Read a line of text at a time from the input, and either copying it to the output or writing a different line instead. Then close both files, delete the input file and rename the output file. This only requires a single line of text in memory at a time, but it's considerably more fiddly.

The second option has another benefit - you can shuffle the files around (using lots of rename steps) so that at *no point* do you ever have the possibility of losing the input file unless the output file is known to be complete and in the right place. That's even more complicated though.